# How to check if two tables are structurally same?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a SQL Server database. I want to check if these two tables are structurally same. I used `UNION/ EXCEPT` operator to check this and found that these two tables are not identical.

Here are my questions:

1. How do we know if two tables are the same in structure?
2. If they are not same, how do we get the details of differences? If a column is missing in one table how do we get the name of the missing column?
3. If there is a data type mismatch between a column in these two tables, can we get the name of the column with different data type?

Comment: You can find the information in information_schema.columns.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Different people may have different interpretations of "same". Some people care about column *order* in their table definitions, whilst others take a purer relational approach and consider tables to be equal if they define the same *set* of columns. It would be helpful to know which of these fits your definition of "same".

Comment: when i say "Same" it means column names and its data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @jarlh commented. you can find the info in information_schema.columns
or, 
you could use this tool called **sql-dbdiff** : https://code.google.com/archive/p/sql-dbdiff/

---

For more idea, you could reffer this discussion: [Easiest Way To Diff Two Table Schemas In SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962324/easiest-way-to-diff-two-table-schemas-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

In SSDT you can use schema compare to see if there is any differences in columns, tables, datatypes and so forth.

[Schema Compare SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690%28v=vs.103%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you want to code your way out of it. You can query information_schema catalog

[System Information Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` you can get info about columns in table/query ... In this sample you can see how to make comparison of column name, nullability, datatype and identity

```
SELECT DEV.name as DEV_ColumnName, 
PROD.name as PROD_ColumnName, 
DEV.is_nullable as DEV_is_nullable, 
PROD.is_nullable as PROD_is_nullable, 
DEV.system_type_name as DEV_Datatype, 
PROD.system_type_name as PROD_Datatype, 
DEV.is_identity_column as DEV_is_identity, 
PROD.is_identity_column as PROD_is_identity  
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE1', NULL, 0) DEV 
FULL OUTER JOIN  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE2', NULL, 0) PROD 
ON DEV.name = PROD.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql Server Management Studio, **right click** on table name

> script table as > CREATE

and you get DDL of the table, this is just a practical way to see the table as it was created. Then of course, as everybody already said, information_schema has all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can compare Tables

If you want to compare tables with the same database just provide same `DATABASENAMESOURCE` and `DATABASENAMEDESTINATION` names

```
use master
go


DECLARE @DB1 VARCHAR(100) = 'DATABASENAMESOURCE';
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(100) = 'TABLESOURCE';


DECLARE @DB2 VARCHAR(100) = 'DATABASENAMEDESTINATION';
DECLARE @Table2 VARCHAR(100) = 'DESTINATION';

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);


SET @SQL = 
'
SELECT 
       Table1.DBName,
       Table1.SchemaName,
       Table1.TableName,
       Table1.ColumnName,
       Table1.name DataType,
       Table1.Length,
       Table1.Precision,
       Table1.Scale,
       Table1.Is_Identity,
       Table1.Is_Nullable,
       Table2.DBName,
       Table2.SchemaName,
       Table2.TableName,
       Table2.ColumnName,
       Table2.name DataType,
       Table2.Length,
       Table2.Precision,
       Table2.Scale,
       Table2.Is_Identity,
       Table2.Is_Nullable
FROM   
    (SELECT  
           ''' + @DB1 + ''' DbName,
           SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) SchemaName,
           t.Name TableName,
           c.Name ColumnName,
           st.Name,
           c.Max_Length Length,
           c.Precision,
           c.Scale,
           c.Is_Identity,
           c.Is_Nullable
    FROM   ' + @DB1 + '.sys.tables t
           INNER JOIN ' + @DB1 + '.sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
           INNER JOIN sys.types st ON St.system_type_id = c.System_Type_id AND st.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE  t.Name = ''' + @Table1 + ''') Table1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
           ''' + @DB2 + ''' DbName,
           SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) SchemaName,
           t.name TableName,
           c.name ColumnName,
           st.Name,
           c.max_length Length,
           c.Precision,
           c.Scale,
           c.Is_Identity,
           c.Is_Nullable
    FROM   ' + @DB2 + '.sys.tables t
           INNER JOIN ' + @DB2 + '.sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
           INNER JOIN sys.types st ON St.system_type_id = c.System_Type_id AND st.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
    WHERE  t.Name = ''' + @Table2 + ''') Table2
    ON Table1.ColumnName = Table2.ColumnName
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Table1.ColumnName IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Table1.ColumnName
'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```